# consecutive convergents

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Problem: Let $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ be the golden ratio and let $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ be positive integers so that $\frac{a}{b}>\phi>\frac{c}{d}$. It is also known that $ad-bc=1$. Prove that $a/b$ and $c/d$ are consecutive convergents of $\phi$.

Numerical experimentations point towards the validity of this statement.
The converse is well known (and easy to show) but I cannot seem to prove the direct statement. 
This is not a homework question; I came across it while investigating the geometric discrepancy of a certain lattice point set. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are consecutive convergents of $\phi$?

Comment: @EnjoysMath: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_(continued_fraction)).

Comment: You are aware that the ratio of consecutive Fibonacci numbers converges to the golden ratio, correct? Not sure if these are the same as the convergents to the usual continued fraction...

Comment: If so, perhaps [Cassini's identity](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassinisIdentity.html) is what you need.

Comment: The convergents are indeed ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $\phi=1+\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{1+\ldots}}$ has convergents $\frac{f_{n+1}}{f_n}$, i.e. ratios of consecutive Fibonacci numbers. Note that I have used lower case for the Fibonacci numbers so as to avoid confusion with the Farey sequence $F_n$.

---

The main idea is to appeal to the properties of [Farey sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

1. Suppose $a, b, c, d$ are positive integers with $a \leq b, c \leq d, \frac{c}{d}<\frac{a}{b}$. Then $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$ are consecutive members of the Farey sequence $F_n$ for some $n$ if and only if $ad-bc=1$.
2. If $\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$ are consecutive members of the Farey sequence $F_n$ for some $n$, then either they are consecutive members in $F_{n+1}$, or $\frac{a}{b}, \frac{a+c}{b+d}, \frac{c}{d}$ are consecutive members in $F_{n+1}$, in which case we have $b+d=n+1$. In other words, as we increase the order of the Farey sequence, $\frac{a+c}{b+d}$ is the first term to appear between $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\frac{c}{d}$.

---

Consider $0<\frac{1}{\phi}<1$.

For each $m$, suppose that the Farey sequence $F_m$ is given by $\frac{0}{1}=a_{m, 0}<a_{m, 1}< \ldots <a_{m, |F_m|-1}=\frac{1}{1}$. We partition the interval $[0, 1)$ into $|F_m|-1$ intervals $[a_{m, i}, a_{m, i+1})$. Note that $\frac{1}{\phi}$ must belong to exactly one such interval. Also note that $\frac{1}{\phi}$ is irrational and so cannot be equal to $a_{m, i}$.

Thus for each $m$, there is a unique pair of rational numbers $r_m, s_m$ s.t. $r_m, s_m$ are consecutive members of the Farey sequence $F_m$ and $r_m<\frac{1}{\phi}<s_m$.

---

Observe that $\frac{1}{\phi}$ has convergents $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$. We observe that for $f_n \leq m<f_{n+1}$, we have that $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ are consecutive members of $F_m$.

**Explanation:** This is because we have the identity $f_{n-2}f_n-f_{n-1}^2=(-1)^{n-1}$, so by property $1$ $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ are consecutive members of some Farey sequence $F_k$. Note that we necessarily have $k \geq f_n$, since $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ is a member of $F_k$. Therefore $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ will be consecutive members in $F_{f_n}$. (Removing elements doesn't affect the fact that they are consecutive) Now, as we increase the order of the Farey sequence, the first term that appears between them is $\frac{f_{n-2}+f_{n-1}}{f_{n-1}+f_n}=\frac{f_n}{f_{n+1}}$, which cannot appear for $m<f_{n+1}$. Therefore $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ remain as consecutive members in the Farey sequence $F_m$, for $f_n \leq m<f_{n+1}$.

Also, as the convergents of $\frac{1}{\phi}$ are alternately greater and smaller than $\frac{1}{\phi}$, we see that $\frac{1}{\phi}$ is strictly between $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$.

Therefore $\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}}$ and $\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}$ must be $r_m$ and $s_m$ in some order, i.e. $\{\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}},\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}\}=\{r_m, s_m\}$.

---

Finally, from the question, $\frac{a}{b}>\phi>\frac{c}{d}$ so $\frac{d}{c}>\frac{1}{\phi}>\frac{b}{a}$. Since $ad-bc=1$, $\frac{b}{a}$ and $\frac{d}{c}$ are consecutive members of some Farey sequence $F_m$. Thus $\{\frac{b}{a}, \frac{d}{c}\}=\{r_m, s_m\}$

Clearly we have $f_n \leq m<f_{n+1}$ for some $n$ so by above $\{r_m, s_m\}=\{\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}},\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}\}$, so $\{\frac{b}{a}, \frac{d}{c}\}=\{\frac{f_{n-2}}{f_{n-1}},\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_n}\}$.

Therefore $\{\frac{a}{b}, \frac{c}{d}\}=\{\frac{f_{n-1}}{f_{n-2}},\frac{f_n}{f_{n-1}}\}$ are consecutive convergents of $\phi$.

Comment: Thanks Ivan; this is very useful. Considering the Farey sequence is the crucial idea. I appreciate the time and effort you put into this.